# Retain rows in an R dataframe which contain a specific pattern in a column

Tags: r, dataframe

`df` is a test dataframe in which I want to retain only the rows which contain the `|` character in the `Hits` column and the rows which contain the *hits* (i.e. Hit1, Hit2 etc.) and also the blank cells in the `Hits` column.

```
df <- data.frame(
 Hits = c("# test114", "# ID|987129470", "# 13135", "Hit1", "", "Hit2", "Hit3", "", "# test739", "# ID|6971324987", "# 83771", "Hit1", "Hit2", "", "Hit3"),
 Category1 = c(NA, NA, NA, 0.001, 0.001, 0.002, 0.003, 0.003, NA, NA, NA, 0.023, 0.341, 0.341, 0.569),
 Category2 = c(NA, NA, NA, 100, 100, 99, 98, 98, NA, NA, NA, 100, 95, 95, 97),
 Category3 = c(NA, NA, NA, 100, 100, 99, 98, 98, NA, NA, NA, 98, 97, 97, 92)
)
```

`df` looks like this

[image]

The output should look something like this

[image]

Since I want to retain only the rows having the `|` character and the ones not having the `#` character and the blank cells, maybe pattern matching could help. But I can't seem to figure out how to implement it in the code. Any suggestions?

Please note that in the original dataframe, the *hits* can have different names. Some *hits* don't start with the term 'Hit'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use `grep` with a regex pattern - `"^[^#]+$|\\|` (Hits column with no `#` from start (`^`) to end (`$`) or (`|`) the `|` character - escaped as it is metacharacter)

```
subset(df, grepl("^[^#]+$|\\|", Hits)|Hits == "")
              Hits Category1 Category2 Category3
2   # ID|987129470        NA        NA        NA
4             Hit1     0.001       100       100
5                      0.001       100       100
6             Hit2     0.002        99        99
7             Hit3     0.003        98        98
8                      0.003        98        98
10 # ID|6971324987        NA        NA        NA
12            Hit1     0.023       100        98
13            Hit2     0.341        95        97
14                     0.341        95        97
15            Hit3     0.569        97        92
```

Or do this in single `grepl`

```
> subset(df, grepl("^$|^[^#]+$|\\|", Hits))
              Hits Category1 Category2 Category3
2   # ID|987129470        NA        NA        NA
4             Hit1     0.001       100       100
5                      0.001       100       100
6             Hit2     0.002        99        99
7             Hit3     0.003        98        98
8                      0.003        98        98
10 # ID|6971324987        NA        NA        NA
12            Hit1     0.023       100        98
13            Hit2     0.341        95        97
14                     0.341        95        97
15            Hit3     0.569        97        92
```

---

or in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
   filter(str_detect(Hits, "^[^#]+$|\\|")|Hits == "")
             Hits Category1 Category2 Category3
1   # ID|987129470        NA        NA        NA
2             Hit1     0.001       100       100
3                      0.001       100       100
4             Hit2     0.002        99        99
5             Hit3     0.003        98        98
6                      0.003        98        98
7  # ID|6971324987        NA        NA        NA
8             Hit1     0.023       100        98
9             Hit2     0.341        95        97
10                     0.341        95        97
11            Hit3     0.569        97        92
```

Comment: I've made an edit to the question. Please check the note

Comment: Thanks. I just looked closely at the original dataframe and found that the duplicate hits are removed, but their associated columns are intact. Rows 5,8,14 have no values in the Hits column. How to deal with this? Should I update the question and include the new dataframe?

Comment: The output matches your expected output

Answer (score 1):

Similar to akruns solution but using no regex solution:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>%
  filter(str_detect(Hits, 'ID|Hit'))
```

```
              Hits Category1 Category2 Category3
1   # ID|987129470        NA        NA        NA
2             Hit1     0.001       100       100
3             Hit1     0.001       100       100
4             Hit2     0.002        99        99
5             Hit3     0.003        98        98
6             Hit3     0.003        98        98
7  # ID|6971324987        NA        NA        NA
8             Hit1     0.023       100        98
9             Hit2     0.341        95        97
10            Hit2     0.341        95        97
11            Hit3     0.569        97        92
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  filter(!str_detect(Hits,"(?=.*#)(?!.*\\|)"))

#>               Hits Category1 Category2 Category3
#> 1   # ID|987129470        NA        NA        NA
#> 2             Hit1     0.001       100       100
#> 3                      0.001       100       100
#> 4             Hit2     0.002        99        99
#> 5             Hit3     0.003        98        98
#> 6                      0.003        98        98
#> 7  # ID|6971324987        NA        NA        NA
#> 8             Hit1     0.023       100        98
#> 9             Hit2     0.341        95        97
#> 10                     0.341        95        97
#> 11            Hit3     0.569        97        92
```